# Android: Hide child dividers in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-widget

I need to completely remove dividers from ExpandableListView. As for parent items it's a setDividerHeight method where I can pass a zero value. But there's no similar method for child divider. Is there any way to hide it?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you want to completely remove dividers from `ExpandableListView`, `setDividerHeight` is ok for both parent and child items. Child divider will be draw using the same height as the normal divider or set by `setDividerHeight()`.

And I am using one work around for us to hide one and unhide the other one, just set the divider and items in the same color like below:

```
 ExpandableListView expView = getExpandableListView();
 expView.setGroupIndicator(null);
 expView.setChildIndicator(null);
 expView.setChildDivider(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.greywhite));        
 expView.setDivider(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.white));
 expView.setDividerHeight(2);
```

`setDividerHeight` must below `setChildDivider` and `setDivider`, or the height will be 0.

Waiting for more answers...

Comment: Of course, if having the spacing for the padding were annoying, you could just set the DividerHeight to 0, and include a divider in the cell used in your custom adapter.

To prevent the bottom item having a separator, you could just hide the separator if index == getGroupCount()-1 && index2 == getChildCount()-1

Answer (score 27):

to hide the child divider set it color to transparent #00000000

define transparent in your color.xml file

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

and then set the child divider

```
listView.setChildDivider(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent))
```

or in the layout xml file

```
<ExpandableListView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:childDivider="#00000000"/>
```

Comment: Setting the divider to a transparent color isn't really removing it.

Comment: alternatively you can use `android:childDivider="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: THis only works if the background behind your list is the same color as your list elements.  If you have a wash color for the background and white for the elements this will not work.

Answer (score 9):

You can use attribute

```
<ExpandableListView 
    android:id="@+id/interestlvExp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:divider="@null">
</ExpandableListView>
```

But this will remove group list divider as well.

Answer (score 3):

instead of writing lengthy code use property `ExpandableListView`.
It will work :-

```
android:childDivider="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: This will hide the divider, not remove it (it will still take up space).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove child divider only, You can create a drawable with same color as of child background color. Then set it as your child divider.

`ShapeDrawable sd1 = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        sd1.getPaint().setColor(YOUR CHILD ITEM BACKGROUND COLOR);
        mExpListView.setChildDivider(sd1);`

Answer (score 0):

Set the divider height of your expandableListView to 0

```
//setDividerHeight(0)
```

And then add a view at the bottom in your headerView xml

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        />
```

Answer (score -1):

android:divider="@color/tranceParent"

```
 <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/tranceParent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:divider="@color/tranceParent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_parent_case"/>
```