# Hide divider without hiding childDivider on ExpandableListView

Tags: android, transparent, expandablelistview, divider

I can't find a way to hide dividers on an ExpandableListView without hiding the child dividers too.

Here is my code.

```
<ExpandableListView 
            android:id="@+id/activities_list"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fadingEdge="none"           
            android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:childDivider="@drawable/list_divider"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

With this code, I get no dividers on groups but no child dividers neither. If I set `android:divider` to `"@drawable/list_divider"` I get both group and child dividers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe this post can help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245234/android-hide-child-dividers-in-expandablelistview][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245234/android-hide-child-dividers-in-expandablelistview

Comment: This post is to hide the child dividers, which is easy to do. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found is to put the child divider directly into the children XML, this way:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/divider"        
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_divider" />
```

which is very very ugly but works.

But still, there should be a way to do that properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
expListView.setDivider(null);
expListView.setDividerHeight(2);
```

this will work

Answer (score 0):

Adding dividerHeight parameter to your ExpandableListView in your xml layout should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

How about just add a line:

android:dividerHeight="0dp"

Actually, i face the similar problem. PD asks the divider and the childDivider are both existed and different, which bothers me much. I am looking for answers too.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion :
-Remove divider in XML :

```
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

-Draw divider in  View getGroupView(..,..,..,..) :

```
            View divider = new View(_context);
            View dividerIDU = new View(_context);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rldivider = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rldividerShort = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    150, 3);

            rldividerShort.setMargins(5, -1, 0, 0);
            dividerIDU.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);


            divider.setLayoutParams(rldivider);
            dividerIDU.setLayoutParams(rldividerShort);

            divider.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(200, 200, 200));

            ((RelativeLayout) convertView).addView(divider);
            ((RelativeLayout) convertView).addView(dividerIDU);
```

-After you can set divider following group position.