# Android expandable listview child divider

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an expandable listview with child view, when ever i click on group view it will expand and display child view, i have to hide divider between parent and child only for the expanded group also make it visible when it collapse, am using default divider, how can i do this.?

Comment: Have you tried the solution found at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3262206/1158886?

Comment: @Vishwanath  look the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is perfect solution.

to hide the child divider set it color to `transparent #00000000`

define transparent in your **color.xml** file

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

and then set the **child divider**

```
listView.setChildDivider(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent))
```

or in the **layout xml** file

```
<ExpandableListView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:childDivider="#00000000"/>
```

here is output :

[image]

for more detail visit here.

[Android: Hide child dividers in ExpandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245234/android-hide-child-dividers-in-expandablelistview)